# how can i get the most flint in the most efficient manner in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to get a large amount of flint for arrows, but how much gravel i dug, It still dropped gravel. only after like digging 20 gravels did I find a piece of flint.

Is there a method to increase my chance of getting flint? can i farm them? I really need these arrows desperately since my aiming is trash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flint normally drops from gravel with 10% probability. If you put Fortune III on a shovel and dig, gravel will drop flint 100% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can farm skeletons to get arrows.

If you want to break gravel effectively ,you can place torches and place gravel 2 blocks up.

(sorry for poor grammar)

Comment: okay. Thanks for your help. I may try to make a skeleton farm.

Comment: @DarthOverlord Also if you put a infinity enchantment on your bow,you will only need one arrow.

Comment: I did not have this luck to have this enchantment  :(   all i get is mending and unbreaking...

Comment: If you do the torch breaking method, it does not drop flint.